# Customize simple membership provider to allow creating of users with the same usernames for different companies in C# .net MVC 4 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership, simplemembership

I have MVC 4 web application and i'm currently using simple membership with three users and 2 roles. My users table looks like this :

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public partial class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public int  CompanyId { get; set; }
}
```

I need to implement a membership that can create users with the same username for different companies, but the websecurity.CreateUserAndAccount method does't allow duplicating usernames. For now i've implemented my own ValidateUsers method that looks like this:

```
public class ExtendedSimpleMembershipProvider
{
    private static IMyProjectRepository myProjectRepository = new MyProjectRepository(new MyProjectEntities());

    public static bool ValidateUser(string username, string password, string companyName)
    {
        int companyId = myProjectRepository.GetCompanyIdByName(companyName);

        int? userId = companyId == 0 ? null : GetUserId(username, companyId);

        if (userId.HasValue && userId.Value != 0)
            return WebSecurity.Login(username, password);
        else
            return false;
    }    

    private static int? GetUserId(string username, int companyId)
    {
        var userId = (from users
                      in myProjectRepository.GetUserProfiles()
                      where (users.UserName.ToLower() == username.ToLower()) && (users.CompanyId == companyId)
                      select users.UserId).FirstOrDefault();
        return userId;
    }
}
```

This validate users works fine. Can i extend the `WebSecurity.CreateUsersAndAccount` to create users with the same usernames for the different companies, without implementing my own membership or only with extending simple membership this would be impossible. I was thinking about something like : Create user only in the userProfile in the database and then add user in the membership table with the already created userId from the userProfile table. This should work, because in the UserProfile table only the UserId is unique and a key.

```
public override static string CreateUserAndAccount(string userName, string password,   object propertyValues = null, bool requireConfirmationToken = false)
{
     if(string != null && password && null && propertyValues.CompanyId != null)
     {
          UserProfile user = new UserProfile();
          user.Name = userName;
          user.CompanyId = propertyValues.CompanyId;
          context.UserProfile.Add(user);
          context.SaveChanges();
     }

     // here create new record in the membership table
}
```

Is this the way to do that ? Or i should take different approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way we've done this on my project is to append a "domain" postfix to the username, based on the client. So you could have a "batman@wayne-enterprises.com" or "batman@whitehouse.gov" in the database. That way we can pretty much use the standard membership provider and just append the postfix before trying to authenticate the user.

Comment: How do you cope with this concatenated username when you need to use it inside the web application : parse the string before the @ every time or ? I've been thinking about this, but it looked like much of complication in the future.

Comment: @dlght: For the moment, we just go ahead and show it. We expect that the vast majority of the time it will correspond with users' email address that they're used to seeing anyway. But at some point if it confuses users, we may separate the notion of the "actual" username from the "displayable" username. As long as you're writing DRY, SOLID code, it shouldn't be difficult to do. But it is just one way, and if you feel another way works better, go for it.